# jnlp file without .jnlp extension? Is jnlp responsible to launch the sandbox?

Tags: java, javascript, jnlp, java-web-start

If jnlp is written in xml then can we have jnlp file with the .xml extension and without any taf of jnlp? Which javascript method is responsible for launching sandbox? may be createWebStartLaunchButton: function(jnlp) or there is some other method?

Answer (score 2):

createWebStartLaunchButton in the deployJava script does simply create a button that when clicked executes javascript-functions that make sure JRE is installed and also allows browser to download and open the jnlp file.

DeployJava documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/deployment_advice.html#deplToolkit

The 'sandbox' or rather the jvm is launched when the jnlp-file is opened by the os-default-handler of jnlp-file-type, usually javaws.exe on windows

If the jnlp file is stored as an .xml on the server it is likely that a servlet or some equivalent is serving it contents by seting response-type

```
response.setContentType("application/x-java-jnlp-file");
```

Which helps the browser to determine how the served file should be opened.

Comment: *"create a button that when clicked executes javascript-functions that make sure JRE is installed"*  The check is done before the button is written.  ;)

Comment: you are propably right. But the actual installing doesnt happen till the button is clicked

Comment: Actually in my whole projcet the name jnlp is used only in deployjava.js. No servlet is having response.setContentType("application/x-java-jnlp-file");

Comment: I have a hard time understanding what you are trying to achieve. I have explained how the jnlp and deployJava relate to each other. Is there a link to a copy of your project that we may look at?

Comment: @AkselWillgert As you mentioned about servlet having response.setContentType("application/x-java-jnlp-file"); will serve the jnlp file but in my whole code there is no servlet like this. IS THERE ANY OTHER WAY TO CREATE JNLP FILE WITHOUT MENTIONING THE WORD "JNLP" BY SERVLET? kindly help... Actually i am totally confused over this type of jnlp file...

Comment: The jnlp file is just a file. But if there is not a servlet specifiying the contenttype, I think it must have the correct suffix (.jnlp) or there is no way for the client to understand how to open it.

Comment: @AkselWillgert That is a big headache i am facing from a month to understand my project, It has mentioned about jnlp in only deployjava.js.